# A confusion with angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS and started learning it recently . I have the following test program -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="rAPP">
  <input type="text" ng-model="mod" ng-init="mod='value1'" />

  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <input type="hidden" id="testInput" ng-model="testInput" ng-init="testInput='value'" />{{ testInput }}
    <span ng-bind="mod"></span>
  </div>


  <script>
    angular.module('rAPP', [])
      .controller('testController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          alert(testInput);
          var counter = 0;

          $scope.$watch("mod", function() {
            counter += 1;
            $scope.mod = counter;
            alert(counter);
          });
        }
      ]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When i execute it , everytime i type in something in the text input , counter increases by 11. For example , once the app loaded , the value in the textbox is value1 and counter is 11 . Next when i make any modification in the textbox , the value jumps to 22. Could not understand why it is happening like that. My hunch was that may be internally the watch listener was called 11 times. So , i tried putting an alert statement inside the listener function and expected it to be shown 11 times , but it is shown once only

Comment: it's shown 11 times for me

Comment: You have a circular dependency. You *watch* `mod` but you change it in the watch handler.

Comment: sorry , remove this line - $scope.mod = counter;

Comment: Then you'll just see "value", not "value1" or "value11". [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/zkuvNL5X6yeKA8whvcUj?p=preview).

Comment: can you explain the circular dependency in detail and how is it causing the listener to run 11 times when i change the value of mod inside listener

Comment: It reaches 10 digest cycle which is cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have params that verify that old value is different from past value, so it increases just once when the value is changed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="rAPP">
  <input type="text" ng-model="mod" ng-init="mod='value1'" />
  <div ng-controller="testController">{{ testInput }}
      <span ng-bind="mod"></span>
  </div>


  <script>
    angular.module('rAPP', [])
      .controller('testController', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            var counter = 0;

            $scope.$watch("mod", function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (typeof newVal !== oldVal) {
                    counter++;
                    alert("counter=" + counter);
                }
            });
        }
      ]);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is infinite loop.

Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop

> 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"mod","newVal":6,"oldVal":5},{"msg":"mod","newVal":7,"oldVal":6}],[{"msg":"mod","newVal":7,"oldVal":6},{"msg":"mod","newVal":8,"oldVal":7}],[{"msg":"mod","newVal":8,"oldVal":7},{"msg":"mod","newVal":9,"oldVal":8}],[{"msg":"mod","newVal":9,"oldVal":8},{"msg":"mod","newVal":10,"oldVal":9}],[{"msg":"mod","newVal":10,"oldVal":9},{"msg":"mod","newVal":11,"oldVal":10}]]

**This is why it is coming** 10+1 as **11**

Lokk at the links for more info : [Angular Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:6,%22oldVal%22:5%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:7,%22oldVal%22:6%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:7,%22oldVal%22:6%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:8,%22oldVal%22:7%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:8,%22oldVal%22:7%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:9,%22oldVal%22:8%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:9,%22oldVal%22:8%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:10,%22oldVal%22:9%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:10,%22oldVal%22:9%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:11,%22oldVal%22:10%7D%5D%5D)

Answer (score 0):

Oh Yeah Got It!

```
Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop
```

> This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and
>   each $digest cycle triggers a state change and subsequent $digest
>   cycle.

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"mod","newVal":6,"oldVal":5},{"msg":"mod","newVal":7,"oldVal":6}],[{"msg":"mod","newVal":7,"oldVal":6},{"msg":"mod","newVal":8,"oldVal":7}],[{"msg":"mod","newVal":8,"oldVal":7},{"msg":"mod","newVal":9,"oldVal":8}],[{"msg":"mod","newVal":9,"oldVal":8},{"msg":"mod","newVal":10,"oldVal":9}],[{"msg":"mod","newVal":10,"oldVal":9},{"msg":"mod","newVal":11,"oldVal":10}]]
```

[Angular Documentation Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:6,%22oldVal%22:5%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:7,%22oldVal%22:6%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:7,%22oldVal%22:6%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:8,%22oldVal%22:7%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:8,%22oldVal%22:7%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:9,%22oldVal%22:8%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:9,%22oldVal%22:8%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:10,%22oldVal%22:9%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:10,%22oldVal%22:9%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22mod%22,%22newVal%22:11,%22oldVal%22:10%7D%5D%5D)

Happy Helping!